# How to specify an interface that must have at least two properties of specific types

Tags: typescript, types, index-signature

This is for the options of a select box. The options must each have one string property that serves as an id, and another property that represents what will be displayed -- in this case a `ReactNode`, however, I don't care what these are called only that there are two properties that meet this criteria. I've tried the following:

```
type Node = string | Array<string>;

interface SelectOption {
  [id: string]: string;
  [el: string]: Node;
}
```

However when I try this Typescript produces the following error: `Duplicate index signature for type 'string'`.

This doesn't produce an error:

```
export interface SelectOption {
  [index: string]: string | Node;
}
```

but is too permissive since it will match an object with only one property (and also redundant because ReactNode includes string).

Is there a way to specify types for two unnamed properties?

Comment: One way to approach it would be to use a conditional type to see if it extends `Record<string, string>` or `Record<string, ReactNode>`, and if either, type `never` - but there may well be a nicer way.

Comment: Is this question specific to React?  If so you might want to tag it as such; if not, you might want to remove the example's dependency on it and provide some other type.

Comment: Seems like a nightmare for the type system, especially if `string extends ReactNode` is true.  I'm interested in implementing it because I'm apparently a masochist, but there's no way you want to do this in TS.  If you care about enforcing some kind of invariant, it's best for you to work with the type system instead of against it, like `{idKey: string, idValue: string, elKey: string, elValue: ReactNode}` and make sure that things work that way.  Even at runtime you'll be happier with this than with the kind of `Object.entries()` weirdness necessary to find the id vs the el

Comment: @jcalz it's definately not specifically related to React, I made it more generic for you

Comment: It's definitely a nightmare; checking for exactly 2 known but unspecified keys, where one but not both properties must be assignable to `Node` and the other property must be assignable to `string` is not something the type system is designed to track.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7P1rm), which gets you close, but it's using some dark recursive conditional magic.  Checking for too many properties is kind of lost cause with TS in general, so even this can be defeated by widening.  You can tell by looking at this example you don't want it anywhere near your code, right?

Comment: Would you like me to write up an answer explaining this?  Or am I missing what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz That looks very complicated. Feel free to write it up, I probably won't actually use it though :) I think you have partially misuderstood the contraint. The object can have other props besides those two, it must however have a minimum of those two. So maybe it can be slightly simpler.

Comment: Can it have properties that are neither `string` nor `Node`?  Like `{a: "", b: node, c: 123}`?

Comment: Assuming you don't have restrictions for properties besides those two, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8JEMm) could be a solution. Still very complicated, and I'd still recommend a different data structure.  If you think I've now understood the constraint, I'll write it up.

Comment: @jcalz I think you have understood the constraint. Frankly I'm struggling to get my head around the code you have written. I think when I finally do understand it, I will have learned quite a bit about typescript. So thank you for writing it. I have saved the code to my computer in case it disappears for whatever reason. If you don't write up an answer I think I might just do it, because I think others can learn from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241534/discussion-between-kaan-a-and-jcalz).

Comment: In your question you say "ESLint produces the following error" but that error looks like it comes straight from the TypeScript compiler itself; it's not just a linter warning, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you refactor your data structure into a format that plays well with the TypeScript type system and the JavaScript runtime.  Here is the shape I'd expect `SelectOption` to have:

```
interface SelectOption {
  idKey: string,
  idValue: string,
  elKey: string,
  elValue: Node
}
```

Now you know exactly what the key for each value is going to be. If you need to process one of these things, you can do so easily:

```
function processSelectOption(selectOption: SelectOption) {
  console.log("id at key " + selectOption.idKey +
    " with string value \"" + selectOption.idValue + "\"");
  console.log("el at key " + selectOption.elKey +
    " with Node value " + JSON.stringify(selectOption.elValue));
}

processSelectOption({ idKey: "id", idValue: "xyz", elKey: "el", elValue: node });
// id at key id with string value "xyz" 
// el at key el with Node value ["a","b","c"]
```

---

Compare this to what you'd need to do with your current data structure, where all you know is that some key has a value of type `string` and some other key has a value of type `Node`:

```
function processSelectOption(selectOption: any) {
// for now, let's use any ---------------> ^^^
  function isString(x: any): x is string { return typeof x === "string" }
  function isNode(x: any): x is Node {
    return ["string", "function"].includes(typeof x) ||
      (Array.isArray(x) && x.every(w => ["string", "function"].includes(typeof w)));
  }
  function findSelectOptionData(selectOption: any) {
    for (const idKey in selectOption) {
      for (const elKey in selectOption) {
        if (elKey === idKey) continue;
        const idValue = selectOption[idKey];
        if (!isString(idValue)) continue;
        const elValue = selectOption[elKey];
        if (!isNode(elValue)) continue;
        return { idKey, idValue, elKey, elValue };
      }
    }
    return;
  }
  const selectOptionData = findSelectOptionData(selectOption);
  if (!selectOptionData) throw new Error("COULDN'T FIND IT");
  // now selectOptionData is the same as the SelectOption I proposed above
  console.log("id at key " + selectOptionData.idKey +
    " with string value \"" + selectOptionData.idValue + "\"");
  console.log("el at key " + selectOptionData.elKey +
    " with Node value " + JSON.stringify(selectOptionData.elValue));
}
```

See how we have to write runtime tests to identity `string` and `Node` values, because they could be on any properties.  And we also have to iterate over all pairs of properties of `selectOption` to find one that's a `string` and a different one that's a `Node`.  (So if `selectOption` has  keys, then you are iterating over O(​²) elements to identify the properties.)  And once you've done all that, you've finally got the same four pieces of information from the `SelectOption` interface I originally proposed:

```
processSelectOption({ id: "xyz", el: node });
// id at key id with string value "xyz" 
// el at key el with Node value ["a","b","c"]
```

And then even once you do this, you might get surprising results:

```
processSelectOption({ el: "node", id: "str" });
// id at key el with string value "node"
// el at key id with Node value "str"
```

Since `string` extends `Node`, there's no way to look at a pair of string properties and figure out which one is "supposed" to be the id and which one is supposed to be the element.  So you have to do a lot of processing just to get to a place where there's ambiguity over what is supposed to be doing what.  That ambiguity gets worse with more properties:

```
processSelectOption({ foo: 123, bar: "baz", id: "str", el: node });
// id at key bar with string value "baz"
// el at key id with Node value "str"
```

Without knowing your complete use case, I can't be certain, but from the outside it looks like such a data structure should be a non-starter. And that's just looking at runtime.

---

In the type system, the same weird ambiguity exists.  The language isn't really geared toward counting how many properties exist and if there is one property of type `A` and some distinct property of type `B`.  There is certainly no specific type that captures this notion, so any hope of writing `interface SelectOption {/*...*/}` or `type SelectOption = ...` is lost.

You *can* express this as a sort of *constraint* on a type.  If you have a candidate type `T`, you can write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type called `AsValidSelectOption<T>` which takes in the candidate type `T` and produces a valid `SelectOption` type which is "close" to `T` in some ill-defined sense.  If `T` is valid, then we want to be sure that `T extends AsValidSelectOption<T>`.  If `T` is not valid, then we want `AsValidSelectOption<T>` to be something valid that's "close" to `T` so that the error messages mention what's wrong in a user-friendly-ish way.

Let's look into that now:

---

First, let's write `AtLeastTwoElements<K>` which takes a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of key-like types `L` and evaluates to [the `unknown` top type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) if there are at least two elements in the `K` union, or else [the `never` bottom type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) id there are fewer than two elements:

```
type AtLeastTwoElements<K extends PropertyKey> =
  { [P in K]: { [Q in Exclude<K, P>]: unknown }[Exclude<K, P>] }[K];
```

This is a nested [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where in the inner types we use [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to successively remove keys from `K`.  If we can do that once and still have keys left over, then there are at least two keys in that union.  `AtLeastTwoElements<"a" | "b">` evaluates to `{a: {b: unknown}["b"], b: {a: unknown}["a"]}["a" | "b"]` which is `{a: unknown, b: unknown}["a" | "b"]` which is `unknown`.  But `AtLeastTwoElements<"a">` is `{a: {}[never], b: {}[never]}["a" | "b"]` which is `{a: never, b: never}["a" | "b"]` which is `never`.  And `AtLeastTwoElements<never>` is `{}[never]` which is `never`.

---

Then, we write `ValidSelectOptionsWithKeys<K>` which takes a union of keylike types `K` and produces a big union of all possible valid `SelectOption` types with these keys:

```
type ValidSelectOptionsWithKeys<K extends PropertyKey> = { [P in K]:
  Record<P, Node> & { [Q in Exclude<K, P>]: Record<Q, string> }[Exclude<K, P>]
}[K] extends infer O ? O extends any ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never : never;
```

That might look complicated, but it's actually quite similar to the way `findSelectOptionData()` works above, by iterating over every key and treating it as a `Node`, and then iterating over every remaining key and treating it as a `string`.  If there are exactly two keys `"a" | "b"` then this is evaluated to something like `{a: {a: Node}&{b: {b: string}}["b"], b: {b: Node}&{a: {a: string}["a"]}}["a" | "b"]` which is `{a: {a: Node, b: string}, b: {b: Node, a: string}}["a" | "b"]` which is `{a: Node, b: string} | {a: string, b: Node}`.  The number of possibilities grows with the number of entries in `K`.  For three keys you have something like `{a: Node, b: string} | {a: Node, c: string} | {b: Node, a: string} | {b: Node, c: string} | {c: Node, a: string} | {c: Node, b: string}`.  So if `K` has  elements then the type produced is a union of O(​²) elements.

---

Finally we build `AsValidSelectOption<T>`:

```
type AsValidSelectOption<T extends object> =
  unknown extends AtLeastTwoElements<keyof T> ? ValidSelectOptionsWithKeys<keyof T> :
  T & (
    "anotherProp" extends keyof T ? { someOtherProp: Node | string } :
    { anotherProp: Node | string }
  );
```

If `T` has at least two elements, then we evaluate `ValidSelectOptionsWithKeys<keyof T>`, which `T` had better be assignable to if it is valid. If `T` has fewer than two elements, then we evaluate `T & {anotherProp: Node | string}` which `T` will almost certainly fail to extend, and the error message will complain that `anotherProp` is missing.  Oh, unless you actually happened to name your one key `anotherProp`, then we complain about `someOtherProp`.  It's probably very unlikely but at least we've covered the bases.

---

In order to test whether some proposed value of type `T` extends `AsValidSelectOption<T>`, we need a generic helper function to pass it to, since only generic functions will infer `T` for us rather than forcing us to manually specify it.  Here's the function `asSelectOption`:

```
const asSelectOption =
  <T extends object>(
    opt: T extends AsValidSelectOption<T> ? T : AsValidSelectOption<T>
  ) => opt as T;
```

Ideally I'd like to write `<T extends AsValidSelectOption<T>>(opt: T) => opt`, but that's a circular constraint.  Instead, we only constrain `T` to `object`, but then have `opt` be of the conditional type `T extends AsValidSelectOption<T> ? T : AsValidSelectOption<T>`.  This will tend to make the compiler choose `T` to be the type of `opt` and then test it.  It's an inference trick.

---

So that was quite a lot of crazy effort to hopefully capture the concept of "one property of type `string` and some distinct property of type `Node`".  Let's at least see if it works:

```
declare const node: Node;

const okay0 = asSelectOption({ a: "", b: node }); 
const okay1 = asSelectOption({ x: node, y: "" });
const okay2 = asSelectOption({ g: "", h: "" });
const okay3 = asSelectOption({ a: "", b: node, c: 123 })

const bad0 = asSelectOption({ a: "", b: 1 }); // number is not Node  
const bad1 = asSelectOption({ a: node, b: node }); // error! 
// Argument of type '{ a: Node; b: Node; }' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '{ a: Node; b: string; } | { b: Node; a: string; }'
const bad2 = asSelectOption({}) // Property 'anotherProp' is missing
const bad3 = asSelectOption({ a: "" }) //  Property 'anotherProp' is missing
const bad4 = asSelectOption({ anotherProp: "" }) // Property 'someOtherProp' is missing
```

Well, that's good, at least.  The `okay*` lines compile without error, because each object conforms to your constraint.  The `bad*` lines have errors in them for one reason or another.  Hooray, I guess!  But oof, at what cost?

---

So there you go.  If you jump through a lot of crazy hoops both at compile time and at run time, you end up with an ambiguous, fragile, and confusing implementation that enforces your constraint and handles (checks notes) four values.  If you refactor your data structure to

```
interface SelectOption {
  idKey: string,
  idValue: string,
  elKey: string,
  elValue: Node
}
```

then you have a straightforward task at both compile time and at run time where the four pieces of relevant information are always in statically known places, and the implementations are robust.  Maybe your use case really makes hoop-jumping more desirable than refactoring, but again, from the outside, I'd be very wary of a project with something like `asSelectOption()` in it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAcgPYAmyAvElMQE4CWwA5kgD5IAxAK7B4xdtWB8kAQVasQpADwsO3acNHjJAPkJJ4klkmB0IALiQ16SJgG0ARCAcAaJA4BGr9-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-ABFH8kEPSN4FWegLzcO8dH-JARFhUwCSkLY7DAiChCg5oYLgjM7D-CIV3IZAViad50UOKAAHUOxmc9Lwga8IFvJAH2oJ8XzaN8mE-b9OCQP9zFxRJDFYWglDvNwNjfAAyPBe2AgSMMgiBoLYuDLFE9IJMAtwyzfNCVKwtScI00cGjQv8rxvWhgk4JI8iQCokAAfmcmyWLswJgCLdy+JAwtqCSZz4IqL8Ai2JBLGACBKScmK4ryIiGlXZAZCgMjaAou1DiUXdPNY6gPAAKyeHjcUQ5CpCY2zghkTdtxYfcjxPFjiHPIKQt3N93KynKfRoui2k6tpgqQHrotxAr5NudV3BAUxSTydiYHxWqvOCLqJrchTRUgCpltYVb1nTfgywzKa-iIf1FuoI6Tp1ZBzrGdQdj+F1emFYwggGtkpAYXF8sK7zirKsQdDm66kA44hLAKjbWIy-rvX+-Lep2yxkcwcjUZqdHcR+Bg31hwJgl3IjIgab6YWoWFFAABlsMm-pqP1AmDbwPBi9NM0FeoaZh+nSAARmZ368buf1Ix5+g3ATfE+a+oxaeFgAmcWvUVf72a4Tm3BJTmMyzAWVaFxQAGZNdZqWOfcLnZYgNx4EsEW1atzMqdNkUYQ8EBaCZpgJe1tnbv1pBuaQMW+aQetgCEMAPCc9hgiWp6iGVn2I-9sWg61j4dbDtM5Yjx3jdCWO8zyE5WAAQlkVguAT9qYZCtKkAAciLjYK8jnuMw7xpU-usmoHYLhQA8MoSGoJA4AUSBcgycb267u3+8jssK6i-h-T7sI7a3gfM+MP3aA1vObckP1M0rtjHzyMhO7uh7H0HlOkDAFOx+4E-ff9q2l9JbXyLgyY2d974cUfkWDuL8SQrTfkPT+38uh-2zrQAALNbYBvpbpLXgcdR8Rtb71lWtAzu+0ICHQIatd+wQv7nFQbsfYNQ54nDOPnSikhgaI1BqVcqNoQ6HHhiDeqmUcbZRwejXaBUsbiIwLjIR3Ceo-GXH8PYWhDhDyKK9cEMsfKkC+JYSMSCLr+lYBAYgQhWBSDSuNExDBHHuDLIrXEGiDiSCHhsW4+jFqGOMUgrsdRroWKsTY3sDgXFuAcO4mo-hMSiFUlAW4diQqRh+LwXg80iC3DkAoUgmIoB5MUD4n4sl5KRiBElVg1oCS2DfI4KJ7hYmHHiZwTC9BkmpMJM6E2lk3EsK0UkTgkilHAAACJNhAIIgurwDGqPmkkdISBbiCyxAiASzJZnfF+NDJASyMirLNvGECWyuHAAWXsvoIVbgnMcUwdZhj-iLk4MMfmVy1mch7EwM5uVJB2EeX4d5ezLQrNrinHR8xbjhn1M6Z54h44QGBdDQWDpvkKm2f8+MQLsnXLBSnbxaLYU-GFAit5uKiChOsbUAMMw3AwuGG4eMTKUz6gzClPZ71rpcr+FSmxyKMy4kFr8n0kziAgGZsM+cV8JlTJmecz6fxQW3FriK-6YqQA-FJCcOpsU6mHnkOkCEABhCoABVDc4zKAdwKgIGclBxlIBnLufkHKcwACpnnGDVTUDVAEKWPI6LogVkwGUjC3hS+MQb5ghoaEStYT0BVRXddmL21MATAlBOCEMBY5Q8h9YcDVHJsRqmhpqDs5J1AVjpGApkOCi1hp5A4PkfTvaikzZKRMbYmyyiLPKAtkgi0nNLddct2ouzVsRCiI0JozS6MtNaAdsrxVVNZcMZ0wKeVsI9OcGV7MmhRhjMmMuSscx5ihD2lsUISyVvLD2KsR7axntbLmos0ob0Tp7H2IcXgBwjgaGm7dHC93+lKMGUw9Awy0GDKoRWrb6wXubAid9FaLqTocBBiADg6xV27Uhos16K2frZZEtg2G3TsM9CB-Z1BqCu3dm4P2rBgx+1jPS6DziyMspPfB89tBX3ZwyDetD97WPYefY2fDxYiPpnQ7Bsc+AthAA)

Comment: Hey @jcalz, I was rereading this answer when it crossed 1k views. Not sure if you are still interested but I noticed that there was a bit of a misunderstanding. The keys that would be Node and string are known at runtime. You can imagine that we have a function `f(option, idKey, nodeKey)` and I was looking for was a way to specify a type for option.

Comment: It's not that I'm not interested per se, but I don't have any clear memory of this (it's, uh, two years old) so I'd have to spend a bunch of time and effort reviewing before I could even begin to respond.  Not sure when that will happen

Comment: FWIW I do the check backwards now. Instead of verifying option, I check to see if option[idKey] would have a string value and option[nodeKey] would have a Node value. This works better because I also allow accessor functions instead of keys so option doesn't necessarily even need to be an object, it could be a string, a symbol or anything as long as a function to generate an id and node from an Option are provided.

Comment: Hey no rush at all. Feel free to ignore it forever and thanks for all your answers. I've learned a lot from you.